# No automatic Bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

There is a build-in solution in Bootstrap to stop the automatic slide of carousel item ?

i'm using this one :

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="carousel-item active">
  <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
  <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
  <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
</div>
</div>
<button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
<span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
</button>
<button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
<span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
</button>
</div>
```

Comment: There's [the 'pause' method](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/carousel/#methods). Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: just find the methode "ride", if it's set to false then there is no automatic slide. Better than the pause but thanks anyway KIKO